# why do I receive ''Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index" when running my program in matlab?

Tags: matlab

**part of my matlab code is as follow:**

```
1-    rawmb=ceil(mbCount/22);
2-     i = rawmb*16-15;
3-     j = colmb*16-15;
4-           
5-            % dy is row(vertical) index
6-            % dx is col(horizontal) index
7-            
8-            dy = mv_MB(1);
9-            dx = mv_MB(2);
10-            refBlkVer = i + dy;
11-            refBlkHor = j + dx;
12-
13- imageComp(i:i+15,j:j+15) = imgI(refBlkVer:refBlkVer+15, refBlkHor:refBlkHor+15);
```

***mbCount*** is a random integer number in the interval [1-396].

***mv_MB*** is a 2*1 column vector.

***imgI*** is a matrix of size [288, 352].

***imageComp*** is a matrix of size [288, 352].

But when I run my program I receive this warning:

***Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index.***

This warning is related to the line 2 (i = rawmb*16-15;). Although I have used ***ceil*** command before, the warning still exist.

I have searched this warning in the mathwork site and their answer was to use **ceil** command to ensure it is an integer number, while I have used it before.

Although I have used this command, I don't know why this warning still exists.

Thank you

Comment: There's no colon operator on line 2 `i = rawmb*16-15;`. I doubt that's the line generating the error.

Comment: Not to mention there is no indexing on that line. I can't see how any line in the code you have posted could produce such an error / warning. Can you post some fully reproducible code? (i.e. if that's yur full code, what is `mbCount` exactly?)

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Wouldn't there be a colon operator somewhere in your code?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `ceil` in your code?

Comment: I have updated the matlab code above.

Comment: Please provide a better description of your problem, fully working code, and don't use any extra characters in your code; remove those "1-", "2-", etc. Essentially, we should be able to run copy/paste and run your code!

Comment: I'd switch from `i=` to `ii=` first. The most suspicious line is `refBlkVer=i+dy` because I don't know whether `dy` is integer or not. And there is perhaps a typo, Steak can be *raw*, but line in matrix or table is *row*

Comment: I can not give you the whole code as it has many functions and I need to give you them all, which is not possible. matlab references the error to line 2 while I have used the _ceil_ for it. _dy_ & _dx_ are integer numbers.

Comment: What about to save significant variables before line 1? It is not mandatory *how* the `mv_MB`, for example, is calculated but *what* is inside. When the faulty variable is found one can ask how it is created.

Comment: Paste the **entire** error message **verbatim**. You also need to post enough code such that the error is reproducible to someone else running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the name of god

Before I want to answer the question I am going to thank from all the friends that gave me their opinions about solution of my problem.

Here, it should be noted that MATLAB was sending the above warning during program runnig for the "LINE 1", while the cause of this warning was due to the non integer values of vector "mv_MV". So, using the ***round*** command  for its values solved the problem.

Now I have a great experience: "The position of errors MATLAB pointing to, is not necessarily the accurate position of mistakes in the code, causing the errors".